# A complex function which is differential only in the closed unit disc.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ be a complex function. As usual, we say that $f$ is **differentiable at $z_0$** if the following limit exists
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}
$$
Can $f$ be differentiable only in the closed unit disc? I cannot find any simple example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$$f(z)=(|z|-1)^2\chi_{\mathbb{C}\backslash\overline{\mathbb{D}}}(z)$$
where $\chi_E(z)$ is one if $z\in E$ and otherwise is $0$

It is clear that $f$ is complex differentiable on the open unit disc and it is not outside the closed unit disc (since $(|z|-1)^2$ is not complex differentiable). It remains to prove that it is differentiable on the boundary.  It suffices to prove that

$$\lim_{z\to z_0\in\partial\mathbb{D}\\z\in \mathbb{C}\backslash\overline{\mathbb{D}}}\frac1{z-z_0}(|z|-1)^2=0\\
\lim \left|\frac1{z-z_0}(|z|-1)^2\right|\le \lim \frac{1}{|z|-1}(|z|-1)^2=0$$

Comment: Thanks @Caffeine. It is a nice example.